# Android Imageview FITXY Image shrinking issue

Tags: android, imageview

`Hi All, I would like to pick an image from my phone gallery and show it as a background of a imageview.I am able to show it and even I am able to make the image fit whole screen via(FITXY property of imageview).

The issue is image actually shrinks , so  I tried Fitcenter and adjustviewbounds property etc and all other properties but no luck , with this properties image fits center and I can see some gaps in(width and height).

Could any one help me on how to fix this issue.
Here is my full code and screenshots for references.

```
<FrameLayout
android:id="@+id/fm"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#70b29c"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/set"
    android:contentDescription="@string/hello_world"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
```

Here is my java code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    sc = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.home);
    Button wal = (Button) findViewById(R.id.setwall);
    wal.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
        }
    });

        @Override  
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent  data) {  

             super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);  
              // check if the request code is same as what is passed  here it is 2
             if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode ==RESULT_OK && null != data) {
                 Uri picUri = data.getData();
                 String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                 Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(picUri,
                         filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                 cursor.moveToFirst();
                 int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                 filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                 cursor.close();
                 bitmapView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.set);
                 bitmapView.setImageBitmap(ExifUtils.rotateBitmap(filePath, decodeSampledBitmap(new File(filePath), 400, 800)));
                 bitmapView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                 SharedPreferences shre = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);
                 SharedPreferences.Editor edit = shre.edit();
                 edit.putString("profilePic", filePath);
                 edit.commit();
             }
          }


 public Bitmap decodeSampledBitmap(File res, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
     if (res != null) {
         // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
         final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
         options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
         try {
             FileInputStream stream2 = new FileInputStream(res);

             BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream2, null, options);

             stream2.close();
         } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         } catch (IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
         // Calculate inSampleSize
         BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
         o2.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);
         o2.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
         FileInputStream stream = null;
         try {
             stream = new FileInputStream(res);
         } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
         Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream, null, o2);
         try {
             stream.close();
         } catch (IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
         return bitmap;
     } else
         return null;
 }

 public int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
     // Raw height and width of image
     final int height = options.outHeight;
     final int width = options.outWidth;
     int inSampleSize = 1;

     if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

         final int halfHeight = height / 2;
         final int halfWidth = width / 2;

         // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
         // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
         while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
             inSampleSize *= 2;
         }
     }

     return inSampleSize;
 }

}
```

Link for the screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2kPc.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using FITXY will fit your image to the imageView regardless of the resolution or aspect ratio of image which will result in inappropriate display of image...

If you want your image to be displayed on the whole screen its better to use CENTER or CENTERCROP which will crop the selected image but set it in image's aspect ratio and will fully cover your view....

Comment: Make adjustViewBound false in your xml file....because adjustViewBound keeps the aspect ratio of the image and also make height and width match parent....also you are using fixed height and width which is resulting in white spaces.

Comment: Hi Arfan just tried CENTERCROP its working great.Thank you for your quick help.

Comment: Yes Arfan, I made it false and its fine now.Thank you.